# How to make apache running on ubuntu docker only accsible via VPN?

Tags: 18.04, apache2, openvpn, docker

I have an Ubuntu 18 installation, on which I have configured and running OpenVPN.
On the same machine I have installed docker and in a container, I run Apache2.
(docker container runs with -p 80:80)

My apache pages are still reachable even without being connected in the VPN.

- How can I achieve that my apache is accessible only via the VPN?
- Is this something that has to do with the docker conf
  or the apache conf?
- How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. 
I just started my container without any port exposure.

Just using: docker run --name WebServer -t -i ubuntu:Apache

I hope this is the right way to do it.